# How can i fix this error in flutter null safety 'error appear when i do a task in form validation

Tags: android, flutter

// Error appear in isEmpty
// I try some tips but doesn't work

```
              validator: (value){
                if(value.isEmpty){
                  return 'name must be Entered';
                }
                return null;
              },
```

Comment: What is the error?!

Comment: 'Null check operator used on a null value' this appear in run / i want to learn how to deal with null safety

Comment: I think the value you are sending to the validator is null, so the function will be like this: validator: (null) {if (null.isEmpty) {...}}   which is the cause of error. before you pass the value to this function make sure it is not null. you can initialize it to something first before passing it to the function.

Comment: The idea of this task is a login screen when i press log in button and the text fields are empty   the message 'name must be Entered' will be print

Answer (score 1):

Check for the value is not null, before doing any operations

```
 validator: (value){
                if(value == null || value.isEmpty){
                  return 'name must be Entered';
                }
                return null;
              },
```

Comment: 'A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.' error appear again

Comment: Which form field is using?

Comment: textFormField   always give red screen in phone screen